# Where python variable was defined

Tags: python, variables

Is there a way to know where a variable was defined in python (e.g. file name)?

I'm experiencing the following problem: in one of project's source file, there is a "print variable" statement, and variable isn't defined in that file, and I can't find where it is defined variable.

Comment: You'll have to give us a lot more. Not for variables, but for *objects* you can usually determine where they were defined, yes.

Comment: Hate being downvoted without knowing the reason.

Comment: I did not downvote your question, but the initial version was *way* to underspecified. The extra information you added shows you actually want to know something completely different from what two people posting answers had to guess for.

Comment: If this is for a one-time task, why not just use a tool like grep (or ack-grep) to search the code for other references to that variable?

Comment: You'll have to include more information. The `print` succeeds? Did you grep for the variable name? Is this in a function, a class, a module?

Comment: So I encountered this issue, and got curious if in python it is possible to get some information about the place (file, maybe line) where variables are defined, because I know it is possible something alike for objects. Regarding to grep, that name occurs way too often.

Comment: Due to Python's dynamic nature, 'variables' are not necessarily defined *at all*. Everything is all keys in dictionaries, in the end, so I can do `sys.modules['somemodule'].newname = 'spam'` and `globals()['spam'] = 'eggs'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not for variables. Variables are just references to arbitrary python objects, and if you can find the variable, you have found the function, class, or the module it is defined in.

I suspect you wanted to know where python *objects* are defined in instead; for many objects that can be determined from the `.__file__` attribute of the object. For classes, you'd have to traverse back it's module first, for methods, traverse to it's function, for functions, find it's code object, for code objects, use their `.co_filename` attribute, etc.

Or use the [`getsourcefile()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcefile) to automate that process:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getsourcefile(inspect.getsourcefile)
'/usr/lib/python2.6/inspect.py'
```

Comment: I was meaning the name, so I think it can't be helped. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky: What do you mean by `name` then? You can inspect the code object, see what local variables are attached to it, get line offsets for the bytecode that refer to them, etc. Painful, but possible.

Comment: Basically, I see a variable, and I don't understand how python knows what it is, my brain would raise a NameError exception instead :). Clearly, it is defined in some outer scope, but I need to investigate.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky: If you have a reference to a function or code object, you can get quite far to figure that out from Python code. But that's not for the faint-of-heart, and requires some in-depth knowledge of Python. Why not just grep for the variable name?

Comment: I was wondering if python offers a direct solution. I search the web and didn't find anything, so I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inspect` module to get information where object was defined: http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcefile